# gpg: problem with the agent: Permission denied

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, gnupg, su

GPG fails with `gpg: problem with the agent: Permission denied` when I invoke it after switching my user with `su`:

```
su - user2
gpg --symmetric --passphrase=foo foo.txt
```

If I invoke the command from my own user, it doesn't fail. Is there a workaround?

I found a thread [a thread in their mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2018-January/059889.html) about it but it's unanswered. It speculates that the error is because:

> the tty is owned by the original user I logged into via SSH, not
>   the user I switched to via su

Comment: Did you try `script -c "gpg --symmetric --passphrase foo foo.txt" /dev/null/`

Comment: I fix it by logging in user2 directly instead `su` from other users.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using the PIN entry mode of loopback:

```
gpg --decrypt --pinentry-mode=loopback <file>
```

I can replicate your issue on my Linux system when I try GPG with a terminal su:

```
$ gpg --decrypt example.gpg
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: problem with the agent: Permission denied
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

The solution that works for me:

```
$ gpg --decrypt --pinentry-mode=loopback example.gpg
hello world
```

You may also want to verify that your GPG is up to date:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.1
...
```

Comment: Can also add
`pinentry-mode loopback` to your ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf file.

Comment: @Deathgrip your comment was more helpful to me than the answer. Every single command requires the --pinetry-mode option, so saving it to the config is a lifesaver.

Comment: Glad I can help

Comment: thank you joelparkerhenderson and @Deathgrip, you are life savers!